# Checkout and zipping a repository via Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, zip, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I am using my Jenkinsfile to do a git checkout --> checkout scm.
I need to zip the repo that is cloned and upload the same into nexus. I have been searching ways to do that, but nothing came to my head. Can any one please suggest?

Regards,
-Ban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [pipeline utility step plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md).

To zip a specify directory or complete workspace you can use below in your pipeline

```
 zip archive: true, dir: '/pathToDirInWorkspace', glob: '', zipFile: 'nameOfFile'
```

If you keep "dir" parameter empty it will zip complete workspace. 
Also if you want to archive the zip file you can set "archive" parameter as true.

U can upload it to nexus using [nexus artifact uploader plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/nexus-artifact-uploader-plugin).
Example is as follow:

```
  nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: [[artifactId: 'art-Id', classifier: '', file: 'artifact.zip', type: 'zip']], credentialsId: 'nexus-creds', groupId: 'com.group', nexusUrl: 'nexus.com', nexusVersion: 'nexus3', protocol: 'https', repository: 'release', version: '1.0.0'
```